# Send line to console in Notepad++

Tags: console, notepad++, interactive, nppexec

Is there a way to execute commands line-by-line written in NPP editor in a console.

I have already looked at the following plugins, but they seem to execute a line or chunk of code as a standalone script (i.e. not interactive):

- NPPExec;
- NPPConsole;

This question is similar to this one:

- [Run selected line in notepad++ console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898873/run-selected-line-in-notepad-console)

but in their case the code is being saved, executed, and stopped. But I would like an *interactive* console, i.e. it would bring up an instance of shell (or any other console), and I can send line-by-line code from NPP editor.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for behaviour similar to [IPython](https://ipython.org/) and [the Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) or maybe just a regular debugger. I don't know of any plugin that can do that in Notepad++.

If interactive behaviour *after* initial execution will do (e.g. for inspection of variables), you can achieve that using [the interactive flag](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Interactive_mode) `-i` in NppExec like this:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
python -u -i $(FILE_NAME)
```